# Layout implementation for Dojo MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, layout, dojo

I started a dojo project from scratch by trying using good practice from the very beginning. I'm really new to dojo toolkit, so I'm walking through lots of documentations and samples which leave me with a lots of cool stuff but no way on how to implement an architecture for future dev (or add-ons). I have searched the web and found this [dojo boilerplate project](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) which seems to be a good start for putting it all together, but I wanted something more, I wanted to implement the MVC pattern (I have lots of experience with JAVA and Ruby on rails dev) in my application and came across this [very cool example](https://github.com/rmurphey/dojo-demo).  So, I created something like this which seems a pretty legit way to organize my project. Correct me, if I'm wrong.. or you have a better approach.

[image: My architecture]

Now, I am ready to start. I have tried a couple of tutorials on dojo toolkit website. Run wonderfully when you only have one page. But right now, I was wondering how would I implement this [layout tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dijit_layout/) into my own application. I want this kind of layout to be my main layout for my application (so, I tried to had those pieces of code into my index.html),

```
<div
        id="appLayout" class="demoLayout"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
        data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
    <div
            class="centerPanel"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div>
            <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Group 2 Content</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Group 3 Content</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div
            class="edgePanel"
            data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)</div>
    <div
        id="leftCol" class="edgePanel"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar content (left)</div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't get:

```
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);
```

So the result is basically the div and my text, but no layout whatsoever. What am I missing?

My solution: I would create only a div on my index (e.g "container") and feed him from the loader (app/run.js), (which call another script called main), this main.js file is using the concept of AMD (which I'm beginning to be familiar), and he's handling the creation of any instance of my application. So, for example, I could create a specific view for my layout and instance it on that file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use also [dojo boilerplate project](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) for my applications and this is my `main.js`:

```
define([ 'dojo/has', 'require', 'dojo/_base/sniff' ], function (has, require) {
    var app = {};

    if (has('host-browser') && isCompatible()) {

        require([ './EntryPoint', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function (EntryPoint) {
            app.entryPoint = new EntryPoint().placeAt(document.body);
            app.entryPoint.startup();
    } else {
        window.location = "/admin/browser/";
    }

    function isCompatible() {
        // browser compatibility check here
    }
});
```

My `EntryPoint` module/class is a widget, i.e. `EntryPoint.js` looks like:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",

    "dojo/i18n!app/nls/main",
    "dojo/text!./ui/templates/EntryPoint.html",

    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/StackContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
], function(
    declare,
    _Widget,
    _TemplatedMixin, 
    _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,

    i18n,
    template
){
    return declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

        templateString: template,
        i18n: i18n,

        postCreate: function() {
            //...
        }

    });
});
```

Finally my `EntryPoint.html`:

```
<div style="height:100%;">
  <div
      data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
      data-dojo-props="design: 'sidebar', gutters: false"
      data-dojo-attach-point="mainContainer"
      style="height:100%;"
    >

    <div
      data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
      data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true, design: 'headline', gutters: false"
      data-dojo-attach-point="sidebarPane"
      class="sidebarPane"
    >

      <div 
          data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
          data-dojo-props="region: 'center'"
      >

        <div class="sidebarSection">${i18n.title.public_}</div>
        <div
            id="sidebar-posts"
            data-dojo-type="app.widget.SidebarItem"
            data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'sidebarIconPosts', value:'posts', name: 'sidebar'">
          ${i18n.title.posts}
        </div>
        <div
            id="sidebar-pages"
            data-dojo-type="app.widget.SidebarItem"
            data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'sidebarIconPages', value:'pages', name: 'sidebar'">
          ${i18n.title.pages}
        </div> 

[...]
```

The advantage of using `Widget` as your main layout:

- html template works out of the box with dojo build system
- you can use `data-dojo-attach-point` and `data-dojo-attach-event` in your layout template
- you can use `${i18n.title.members}` for string substitution in html

Comment: Very neat! I have just done something quite similar, but instead I create each instance for each container (e.g. applayout.js, sidebar.js, etc.) and just constructed everything within my main.js . But I believe your way of doing is better, because I can imagine separating too much can bring up the complexity. As for your html, I didn't know you could actually do that "dojo/text!./ui/templates/EntryPoint.html" ... pretty awesome stuff.

Comment: I still have a question. I tried to do exacly what you did... and I get the same result as b4? So, basically, I still get the templateString, but there's no widget at all... "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/StackContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane" are not loading properly I guess!

Comment: Assuming your `dojoConfig` is set to `parseOnLoad:true`. Dijit template, e.g. _EntryPoint.html_, must have just one root element otherwise widget instantiation will fail. It is also possible your `dijit/layout` was parsed and instantiated properly (check it via [Firebug Dojo Extension](http://goo.gl/KB5rq)), but it's not styled properly and therefore its height is just the height of its content (often 0px). All enclosing nodes of `dijit/layout` w/ height in percentage should have explicitly defined `height`. In my example it means `html, body {height:100%;}` and the template root node.

Comment: I just realized there is no need for `parseOnLoad` because `EntryPoint` layout widget is created programatically in _main.js_.

Comment: hmm weird... I added a <div style="height:100%;"> HTML CONTENT </div> and it worked? Sounds like templateMixin added a "unwanted" behavior and changed the id/class of my div root.. anyways its fixed. Thanks again.