# Simple Login implementation for Dojo MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

Is there any example on how to implement a simple login page/dialog? I have been trying to do it with dojo boilerplate (check my previous questions : [Layout implementation for Dojo MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953316/layout-implementation-for-dojo-mvc)). So far, I have been able to display my dialog box. But I want to be able to get my data and on click event want to have an alert box for example (with his content).

My view:

```
<form action="Login" method="post" validate="true" id="loginForm">
  <table width="258">
    &nbsp;
    <tr>
      <td><label>Login</label></td>
      <td><input class="cell" type="text" trim="true" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" value="" name="login" id="userId"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Password</label></td>
      <td><input class="cell" type="password" trim="true" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" value="" name="password" id="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top"><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" id="LoginButton" onClick="connect">Ok</button></td>
            &nbsp;
            <td align="left" valign="top"><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" onclick="document.Login.reset()" id="Cancel">Cancel</button></td>
            &nbsp;
            <td><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" onclick="showDialog();" id="resetPassword"> Show Dialog </button></td>
          </tr>
     </table>
     &nbsp;
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

My Widget module/class

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!app/views/Login/Login.html",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dijit/form/TextBox"
], function(
    declare,
    _Widget,
    _TemplatedMixin, 
    _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    template,
    Dialog
){
    return declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Dialog], {

        templateString: template
    });
});
```

Now, if you check the HTML the element id LoginButton should call in this case a "connection" function. Which should show (on an alert box) the username and password current input.

Where do I put my function? kind of...

```
    connect : function(){
    alert("username :" + dom.byId("userId").value() 
+ "  Password: " + dom.byId("password").value());
    }
```

**EDIT: New code**

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!app/views/Login/Login.html",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dijit/form/TextBox"
], function(
    declare,
    dom,
    _Widget,
    _TemplatedMixin, 
    _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    template,
    Dialog
){
    return declare("login", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Dialog], {

        templateString: template,

        postCreate: function() {
           this.inherited(arguments);
           // make reference to widget from the node attachment
           this.submitButton = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(this.submitButtonNode);
           // override its onSubmit
           this.submitButton.onClick = function(){
             alert("username :" + dom.byId("userId").value() 
                 + "  Password: " + dom.byId("password").value());
           };
        },
        // and a sample on how to implement widget-in-template stateful get/setter pattern
        // e.g. if submitbutton label should change on some event, call as such:
        // dijit.byId('loginForm').set("submitLabel", "Sendin login, please wait");
        _setSubmitLabelAttr : function(value) {
            return this.submitButton.set("label", value);
        },
        _getSubmitLabelAttr : function() {
            return this.submitButton.get("label");
        },
    });
});
```

My main.js:

```
define([ 'dojo/has', 'require', 'dojo/_base/sniff'], function (has, require) {
    var app = {};

    if (has('host-browser')) {

        require([ './views/Login', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function (Login) {
            app.login = new Login().placeAt(document.body);

            app.login.startup();

            // And now…
            app.login.show();
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Hello from the server!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Check out my answer to [Dojo Dialog with confirmation button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button/10405938#10405938) and example [code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/wkydY/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to add my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/tG8Sg/

It is a bit twisted due to constrains of jsFiddle, but the main principles are the same as I employ in my coding.

First of all, the login process (or any other form processing) is encapsulated inside the dialog and it communicate with the rest of the application thought emitting evens via `dojo/Evented`. This is how it works:

```
var loginDialog = new LoginDialog({ controller: loginController});
loginDialog.startup();
loginDialog.show();

loginDialog.on("cancel", function() {
    console.log("Login cancelled.");        
});

loginDialog.on("error", function() { 
    console.log("Login error.");
});

loginDialog.on("success", function() { 
    console.log("Login success.");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.get("value")));
});
```

As you can see in the jsFiddle, there are two templates *dialog-template* and *login-form-template* which I assemble inside the `LoginDialog` constructor. The reason is I would normally have also a class wrapping `dijit/form/Form` to do some magic beyond standard `dijit/form/Form` validation and data serialization, but since login is simple and it'd be a mess in the single file of jsFiddle, I got rid of it. The advantage of separating a form from a dialog is you can use the same form (i.e. *View*) together with all the form ad hoc code somewhere else, e.g. in a `ContentPane`. The form is there just to display and gather data to/from user, it should not directly communicate with *Model*, i.e. web service, there is a *Controller* for that purpose:

```
var LoginController = declare(null, {

    constructor: function(kwArgs) {
        lang.mixin(this, kwArgs);
    },

    login: function(data) {
        // simulate calling web service for authentication
        var def = new Deferred();
        setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function() {
            def.resolve(data.username == this.username && data.password == this.password);                
        }), 1000);
        return def;
    }
});
```

Create an instance of `LoginController`:

```
// provide username & password in the constructor
// since we do not have web service here to authenticate against    
var loginController = new LoginController({username: "user", password: "user"});
```

and pass it to `LoginDialog` constructor as yet seen above:

```
var loginDialog = new LoginDialog({ controller: loginController});
```

Finally `LoginDialog` class:

```
var LoginDialog = declare([Dialog, Evented], {

    READY: 0,
    BUSY: 1,

    title: "Login Dialog",
    message: "",
    busyLabel: "Working...",

    // Binding property values to DOM nodes in templates
    // see: http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/10/02/lessons-in-widgetry-binding-property-values-to-dom-nodes-in-templates/
    attributeMap: lang.delegate(dijit._Widget.prototype.attributeMap, {
        message: {
            node: "messageNode",
            type: "innerHTML"               
        }            
    }),

    constructor: function(/*Object*/ kwArgs) {
        lang.mixin(this, kwArgs);            
        var dialogTemplate = dom.byId("dialog-template").textContent; 
        var formTemplate = dom.byId("login-form-template").textContent;
        var template = lang.replace(dialogTemplate, {
            form: formTemplate                
        });

        var contentWidget = new (declare(
            [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],
            {
                templateString: template                   
            }
        )); 
        contentWidget.startup();
        var content = this.content = contentWidget;
        this.form = content.form;
        // shortcuts
        this.submitButton = content.submitButton;
        this.cancelButton = content.cancelButton;
        this.messageNode = content.messageNode;
    },

    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        this.readyState= this.READY;
        this.okLabel = this.submitButton.get("label");

        this.connect(this.submitButton, "onClick", "onSubmit");
        this.connect(this.cancelButton, "onClick", "onCancel");

        this.watch("readyState", lang.hitch(this, "_onReadyStateChange"));

        this.form.watch("state", lang.hitch(this, "_onValidStateChange"));
        this._onValidStateChange();
    },

    onSubmit: function() {
        this.set("readyState", this.BUSY);
        this.set("message", ""); 
        var data = this.form.get("value");

        // ask the controller to login
        var auth = this.controller.login(data);

        Deferred.when(auth, lang.hitch(this, function(loginSuccess) {
            if (loginSuccess === true) {
                this.onLoginSuccess();
                return;                    
            }
            this.onLoginError();
        }));
    },

    onLoginSuccess: function() {
        this.set("readyState", this.READY);            
        this.emit("success");
    },

    onLoginError: function() {
        this.set("readyState", this.READY);
        this.set("message", "Please try again."); 
        this.emit("error");         
    },

    onCancel: function() {
       this.emit("cancel");     
    },

    _onValidStateChange: function() {
        this.submitButton.set("disabled", !!this.form.get("state").length);
    },

    _onReadyStateChange: function() {
        var isBusy = this.get("readyState") == this.BUSY;
        this.submitButton.set("label", isBusy ? this.busyLabel : this.okLabel);
        this.submitButton.set("disabled", isBusy);
    }            
});
```

Please see templates at the aforementioned [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/tG8Sg/). They should be in separate files `required` via `dojo/text!` normally. I put them into `<script type="text/template">` to fit into jsFiddle.

Comment: Thank you. The code is from my [Dojo 1.7 based project](http://cms.egoworx.com/) I would like to publish on GitHub. It's CMS + CMS Admin, i.e. basically a CRUD application build upon `dojo/store/JsonRest` and [`dgrid`](http://dgrid.io). It also includes a RESTful back-end written in Zend Framework, so I think it might be helpful as it's not too simple nor too complicated example, which is missing in the Dojo ecosystem. I will let you know when published if you are interested.

Comment: You saw my other posts... I'm grabbing pretty much any informations regarding dojo. So yes, I'm pretty interested. I have a very specific question for you. How do you infrastructure your website with dojo? How do you separate your files? like for your login example. I believe I would create a file for : dialog-template.html, login-form-template.html (under something like app/views/templates), then same deal with the login js logic (app/views/LoginDialog.js) and one for the controller (app/controllers/LoginController.js).. and my index.html calls those two? Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I do it exactly that way, but I like naming templates in the same manner as js classes, so a template for `LoginDialog.js` would be `templates/LoginDialog.html`. Every _namespace_ has its _templates_ directory if needed, like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2131149/dojo-directory-structure.png

Comment: Last question. I see you are using dojo boilerplate. How does "instance" works? For example, if we continue with your login example, how do I create it (make it show) in main.js ...

Comment: I'm not sure what do you means w/ "instance". I think there should not be any more logic inside _main.js_, its there just to fire up application which starts with `EntryPoint.js`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12499/discussion-between-fneron-and-phusick)

Comment: Hello again! I was wondering if you were considering putting your project on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It's helped me fill in the blanks for a project I'm working on. I do have a question for you regarding the _onValidStateChange if you have time, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28047/quick-chat-about-dojo-form-state . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seing as you template the widget, you would want to make use of the templated widget parse. Taken from http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/ below describes how to attach an event to a simple domnode.

```
<div 
  data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode"
  data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick"
  role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></span>
</div>
```

Seing as you have widgets in template, make references to your child-widgets and set their properties through these references.

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
  <button 
     id="LoginButton"  type="submit" 
     dojoType="dijit.form.Button"
     dojoAttachPoint="submitButtonNode">
        Ok
   </button>
</td>
```

Create a folder so it becomes 'sibling' to dijit/dojox/dojo folders, call it 'app'. And following widget declaration, put in a file called app/widget/MyWidget.js under;

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_Widget",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"dojo/text!app/views/Login/Login.html",
"dijit/Dialog",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dijit/form/TextBox"

], function(
    declare,
 _Widget,
_TemplatedMixin, 
_WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
template,
Dialog

){
    return declare("app.widget.MyWidget", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Dialog], {

        templateString: template
        postCreate: function() {
           this.inherited(arguments);
           // make reference to widget from the node attachment
           this.submitButton = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(dojo.query(".dijitButton")[0], this.domNode);
                 // or simply dijit.byId('LoginButton');
           // override its onSubmit
           this.submitButton.onClick = function(){
             alert("username :" + dom.byId("userId").value() 
                 + "  Password: " + dom.byId("password").value());
           };
        },
        // and a sample on how to implement widget-in-template stateful get/setter pattern
        // e.g. if submitbutton label should change on some event, call as such:
        // dijit.byId('loginForm').set("submitLabel", "Sendin login, please wait");
        _setSubmitLabelAttr : function(value) {
            return this.submitButton.set("label", value);
        },
        _getSubmitLabelAttr : function() {
            return this.submitButton.get("label");
        }
    });
});
```

And once files are in place, write your html like so:

```
<head>
   <script src=...dojo...></script>
   <script>
      dojo.require([ 
        "dojo/parser", 
        "app/widget/MyWidget",
        "dojo/domReady!" ] , function(parser) {

          parser.parse();

      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form dojoType="app.widget.MyWidget"></div>
</body>
```

This will do following:

- load the dojotoolkit (dojo/dojo.js)
- create a namespace called 'app' which has a subspace 'widget'
- render body (the simple form dom node)
- call script ondomready, requireing `app.widget.MyWidget`
- MyWidget requires the dependencies
- parser.parse instantiates the `<form dojoType="mywidget">`

Comment: I am getting an error in firebug: "declare Login : mixion #0 is not a callable constructor.

Comment: i hope your mixin#0 was not '...' right? :) ive filled in blanks in answer

Comment: this  dijit.getEnclosingWidget(this.submitButtonNode) return me null? I don't know if you had a look at dojo boilerplate, but basically there' s a file main.js where I call my dialog. check my edit.

Comment: ah ok, i am guessing that the `<button dojoType...>` node is destroyed and replaced with another domnode (one from the dijit.Button.templateString). Basically the aim of calling getEnclosingWidget was to request the widget dijit.Button from its domNode reference - which has changed during parsing. So wont work, my bad.. Try in postCreate do `dijit.getEnclosingWidget(dojo.query(".dijitButton")[0], this.domNode)` or `this.getChildren()[ButtonIndex]`

Comment: haha! It's all good. Unfortunatelly, those 2 lines doesn't work I still get this.submitBtton is undefined. Why I just can't create a function and call it as an event?

Comment: what does this.getChildren() return in postCreate()? if the result array length is 0, try moving it to startup().. And if so, im quite sure dijit.byId('SubmitButton') also is undefined. Once widgets in template kicks in, lifecycle gets a little fuzzy, instance should be created during parse but not nescessarily initialized fully before 'onShow' event. In all your override functions, make sure to call this.inherited(arguments) before acting.

Comment: Actually, I made it "work with dojo.connect(this.loginButton, 'onclick', this._login)... and get the textbox values to display on my alert box (within the _login function), but everytime I click on my browser I get an alert box?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of mschr. I came accross this particular solution.

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/dom",
"dijit/_Widget",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"dojo/text!app/views/Login/Login.html",
"dijit/Dialog",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dijit/form/TextBox"

], function(
    declare,
    dom,
 _Widget,
_TemplatedMixin, 
_WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
template,
Dialog
){
    return declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Dialog], {

        templateString: template,

        postCreate: function() {
           this.inherited(arguments);
           // make reference to widget from the node attachment
           //this.submitButton = this.getChildren()[ButtonIndex];
           // override its onSubmit
             /*alert("username :" + dom.byId("userId").value() 
                 + "  Password: " + dom.byId("password").value());*/
            dojo.connect(this.loginButton, 'onclick', this._login);
        },
        // and a sample on how to implement widget-in-template stateful get/setter pattern
        // e.g. if submitbutton label should change on some event, call as such:
        // dijit.byId('loginForm').set("submitLabel", "Sendin login, please wait");
        _login : function() {
            var value = dom.byId("userId").value;

            if(value)
                alert("username: " + value);
        },
        // and a sample on how to implement widget-in-template stateful get/setter pattern
        // e.g. if submitbutton label should change on some event, call as such:
        // dijit.byId('loginForm').set("submitLabel", "Sendin login, please wait");
        _setSubmitLabelAttr : function(value) {
            return this.submitButton.set("label", value);
        },
        _getSubmitLabelAttr : function() {
            return this.submitButton.get("label");
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Do not use `dojo.connect` otherwise your dialog will not be garbage collected until you manually disconnect this handler. Also `_login()` method will not be called in the scope of your dialog, so e.g. `this.loginButton` will not be available inside `_login()`, you will have to write `dojo.connect(this.loginButton, "onClick", lang.hitch(this, "_login"))` to achieve this. Use `this.connect(this.loginButton, "onClick", "_login")` instead, `_login()` will be called in the dialog scope and the connect will be automatically disconnected in the time the dialog is being destroyed.

Comment: Also please note that using `dom.byId()` causes you to use the dialog as a singleton, which might be ok with a login dialog, but you will not be able to control `id`s of DOM nodes and dijits across whole application. You should not use `id`s inside dijit templates, use `data-dojo-attach-point` instead.