# How to make and display a form in a Dijit Dialog programmatically?

Tags: forms, dojo, dialog

I've been trying to figure out how to create and display a form inside of a Dialog using Dojo 1.7.

I want my dialog to look something like this:

[image]

All the samples I have seen do it using Markup, but none using AMD

Comment: Speaking about dialogs and Dojo, you may consider reading my answers to [Simple Login implementation for Dojo MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984855/simple-login-implementation-for-dojo-mvc/11017097#11017097) and [Dojo Dialog with confirmation button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button/10405938#10405938).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you create a dialog, you can use a widget (e.g. a form) as content. So, for example, you could do:

```javascript
require([
    "dijit/Dialog", 
    "dijit/form/Form", 
    "dijit/form/TextBox", 
    "dijit/form/Button", 
    "dojo/domReady!" 
], function(Dialog, Form, TextBox, Button) 
{
    var form = new Form();

    new TextBox({
        placeHolder: "Name"
    }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

    new Button({
      label: "OK"
    }).placeAt(form.containerNode);

    var dia = new Dialog({
        content: form,
        title: "Dialog with form",
        style: "width: 300px; height: 300px;"
    });
    form.startup();
    dia.show();
});//~require
```

`require()` is provided by Dojo. It loads the dependencies (Form, Dialog etc) and then runs the given function which creates the widgets. However, because we include `domReady!` among the dependencies, Dojo makes sure the DOM is fully loaded and ready first.

Because I have `dia.show()` in that function too, the dialog will actually be shown as soon as the page is opened. Let's say you wanted to show the dialog when some button on your page is clicked instead:

```javascript
require([
    "dijit/Dialog", 
    "dijit/form/Form", 
    "dijit/form/TextBox", 
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/on",      // Added this!
    "dojo/domReady!" 
], function(Dialog, Form, TextBox, Button, onEvent) 
{
    // ... as above, we create the dialog and form when the page loads
    // but it remains hidden until we call dia.show() ...
    form.startup();
    // dia.show();  Commented out this!

    onEvent(document.getElementById("someButtonOnYourPage"), "click", 
        function()
        {
            dia.show();
        });
});//~require
```

Comment: sorry for the noobish question, but how would I call this function?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I updated the answer. You would usually call require when the page loads, even if you don't want the dialog to show until later on (but you don't have to, of course).

Comment: This just fixed the "Tried to register widget with id==xx but that id is already registered" error.  I had be doing: myDialog.set("content", popup.domNode);

Changed it to myDialog.set("content", popup); after finding this question/answer and my extra errors are gone!  Thank you both!